# Multiply and shift the result in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have two 8-bit unsigned vectors named a and b, and 16-bit unsigned vector called result. I want to compute a * b * 4 and assign it to result. I do not care about overflow because I know that it will not happen for some reason, it is not important. Is the following way correct?

```
result <= a * b;
result <= result(13 downto 0) & "00";
```

(Assume these two lines are in a clocked process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. It will just assign to `result` its previous value left-shifted by 2 positions. This is due to the simulation semantics. To make it short, if you assign several times the same signal in a process, during the same simulation step, the last assignment overrides the others, just like if they did not exist. In your case you can delete the `result <= a * b;` line, it will behave the same. And of course, synthesizers implement something that has the same behaviour.

Use an intermediate variable, maybe:

```vhdl
process(...)
  variable tmp: unsigned(15 downto 0);
begin
  ...
  tmp := a * b;
  result <= tmp(13 downto 0) & "00";
  ...
end process;
```

Variant:

```vhdl
process(...)
  variable tmp: unsigned(17 downto 0);
begin
  ...
  tmp := (a & '0') * (b & '0');
  result <= tmp(15 downto 0);
  ...
end process;
```

And I recommend finding and reading a good book about VHDL that explains the semantics of the language, especially the difference between variables and signals, the delayed assignment of signals... Note that understanding this will also be very helpful to program with other HDLs like SystemVerilog or SystemC.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Renaud! Do you have any book recommendation?

Comment: No, sorry I don't have a specific book to recommend. I tried to use some books for my teaching activity but I have always been dissatisfied by one or several important aspects. I know prefer creating my own teaching material. Some time ago SO had a _documentation_ section with a VHDL chapter that I contributed a lot. Finally the documentation section was removed but I just discovered that my main contributions have been recycled [here](https://riptutorial.com/vhdl). Have a look, maybe?

Comment: I recommend starting with [Signals vs. variables, a brief overview of the simulation semantics of VHDL](https://riptutorial.com/vhdl#signals-vs--variables--a-brief-overview-of-the-simulation-semantics-of-vhdl). Then [Digital hardware design using VHDL in a nutshell](https://riptutorial.com/vhdl/topic/5525/digital-hardware-design-using-vhdl-in-a-nutshell). And finally, read everything else, in any order. Have fun.